# Using week number based on specific (startdate and enddate) in one file to search for match in master directory

Tags: python, pandas

I have a correct list of week numbers based on my startdate and enddate. Then, with those week numbers, I would like to iterate through the master directory to load each file and directly append them.

Here's my code:

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\shakir\\Desktop\\FY20") #directory

start_date = pd.to_datetime('2019/1/1') #Input date
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2019/2/1') #Input date

data_file = 'C:\\Users\\shakir\\Desktop\\FY20'
sched = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\shakir\\Desktop\\FY20\\wm_sched.csv", parse_dates=[1,2])

# determine what weeks to load into dataframes 
month = 1
weeks = []

for i in sched.index:
    if (month == sched.loc[i,'start_incl'].month) | (month == sched.loc[i,'end_excl'].month):
weeks.append(sched.loc[i,'weeknum'])

all_files = []

spath = r'C:\\Users\\shakir\\Desktop\\FY21'
filename = os.listdir(spath)

for f, item in enumerate(filename):
    if (weeks == filename[f+1, 'date']):
        all_files.append(filename[f+1, 'date'])

print(all_files)
```

I expected to have output from the range of date selected as one file in excel.

Comment: what is your issue so far ? How your code is not working ?

Comment: @BenoitDrogou Is showing TypeError: 

----> 7     if (weeks == filename[f+1, 'date']):
      8         all_files.append(filename[f+1, 'date'])
      9 print(all_files)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: between the `for` and the `if` can you do `print('Week's type, type(week), '\nFilename\'s type', type(filename[f+1, 'date']))

Comment: I believe week is a list and the other one is a tuple

Comment: @BenoitDrogou The week is a list while the file showing below message. I'm still a beginner in coding and only learning by doing. Please, help me.

----> 2 type(filename[f+1, 'date'])

TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Comment: well I do not know what is in your file. I would like to see what `f` is

Comment: @BenoitDrogou Sorry for my late response, been offline. see below for the type of file I have. Note: The data in each file is more than what I have below here and consists of strings, int, and float. I have these types of files in different 27 folders, while each folder has 2 separate files.

`code` record              uuid                date  \
 0     189374  jh8gbmw4m6b6rcx6 2019-02-26 19:29:00   
 1     207276  awea49cu60us2zqq 2019-02-23 18:04:00   
 2     208182  jg15r2drcucxftdd 2019-02-26 21:42:00 `code`